# webclient calls callback before completion c#

Tags: c#, webclient

Webclient.DownloadFileAsync calls the callback function before the file is completely downloaded.

```
webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(DownloadGameCompletedCallback);
            webClient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("i dont want to leak game but link is here"), gameZip, _onlineVersion);
```

Comment: @jdweng What? Did you comment the right question?

Comment: How do you observe that the file is not yet completely downloaded when that event is being raised?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen : Yes.  The OP is using AsyncCompletedEventHandler which need to know when end of data occurs.  A standard Async complete isn't looking at the tags and will trigger when data stops being received.

Comment: But what tags are there to look at here? A file is being downloaded, and if the link points to a (dynamic) web page, you should still get the whole thing, the tags shouldn't be relevant here. Considering that the other parameter to the method call is `gameZip`, I don't see what role tags have to play with this at all.

Comment: I see the file is not complete cause it downloads like a part of it or something. in other words. The file is 321 mb but it only downloads 7 kb and then calls the callback.

Comment: Have you checked the contents of those 7kb? Perhaps what you're getting is a login page?